# CSS filter confusion

Tags: html, css

So I've been trying to solve this problem for 2 hours, I tried and searched a lot  but didn't find anything, I'll appreciate it if someone help me.
I have this problem where I give a `div`'s background a filter and the css file that does it for me has:

```
#carousel {
  width: 1366px;
  height: 512px;
}

#carousel-next>div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 208px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 208px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  filter: brightness(125%); /* Current draft standard */
  -webkit-filter:brightness(125%); /* New WebKit */
  -moz-filter: brightness(125%);
  -ms-filter: brightness(125%); 
  -o-filter: brightness(125%); /* Not yet supported in Gecko, Opera or IE */ 
}

#carousel-next>div:after {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(240,132,24,.75);
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#carousel-prev>div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 208px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(25%); /* Current draft standard */
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(25%); /* New WebKit */
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(25%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(25%); 
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%) brightness(25%); /* Not yet supported in Gecko, Opera or IE */ 
  filter: url(resources.svg#desaturate) brightness(25%); /* Gecko */
  filter: gray brightness(25%); /* IE */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1) brightness(25%); /* Old WebKit */
}

#carousel-next, #carousel-prev {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 458px;
  right: 81px;
}
```

And my html file is:

```
<div id="carousel" style="background: url('images/kill.jpg');">
<a href="#" id="carousel-next">
    <div style="background:url('images/next.jpg');"><span>next</span></div>
</a>
<a href="#" id="carousel-prev">
    <div style="background:url('images/previous.jpg');"><span>previous/span></div>
</a>
```

I'm a little bit confused but I'll try to explain it:
The filters that I added to the `div`s to affect the backgrounds also affect the `span`, which I don't want to, I tried applying different `z-index`es to the `span` but it's still the same, I also tried making the filter affects `:after` of the `div` but it got me more confused.

Comment: did you see my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `<span>` is nested within the div that has your filter styling. Take it out and the styling will not be applied.

Comment: For some reason when I take out the `span` outside the `div`, the `span` becomes behind the `div`.

Comment: Never mind, fixed up by setting the `span` position to `absolute`